# Correct way of returning Promise/Observable from Angular Material Dialog

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, observable

I have project that should be rewritten from old angularJS into new angular. Previously it used angular-bootstrap library for rendering modals. In result it returned Promise after modal close event. What is correct way to replicate similar behaviour in angular material? Not Promise, but Observable.

I tried this

```
confirmation(title: string, content: string, okCallback: () => void, cancelCallback: () => void): Observable<any> {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MxConfirmationDialog, {
    data: {title, content}
  });

  const closeResult = dialogRef.afterClosed();

  closeResult.subscribe(result => {
    if (result && okCallback) {
      okCallback();
    }
    if (!result && cancelCallback) {
      cancelCallback();
    }
  });

  return closeResult;
}
```

Calling confirmation dialog:

```
dialogService.confirmation(
      'Title',
      'Message',
      () => true, 
      () => false
    )
```

In my case `closeResult` a value of is modal closed or not... but not result of callbacks...

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are actually returning the `closeResult`
you need to return the values of your callbacks as observables using `of` operator.

```
  confirmation(
    title: string,
    content: string,
    okCallback: () => void,
    cancelCallback: () => void,
  ): Observable<any> {

     const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MxConfirmationDialog, {
       data: {title, content}
    });

    const closeResult = dialogRef.afterClosed();

    closeResult.subscribe((result) => {
      if (result && okCallback) {
        // return the results of callback as observables
        return of(okCallback());
      }

      if (!result && cancelCallback) {
        return of(cancelCallback());
      }
    });

    // base case
    return EMPTY;
  }
```